# Function of と in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-と

I'm struggling with figuring the function of the particle と in this sentence from a book of Japanese literature in parallel text from the beginning of [夏目漱石's 夢十夜](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000148/files/799_14972.html):

> 腕組をして枕元に坐っている**と**、仰向に寝た女が、静かな声でもう死にますと云う。

The parallel text to this sentence translates this to:

> I was sitting with my arms crossed by the bedside of a woman. She was lying on her back. 
>  . . .

I do understand how the sentence was thus translated; however, I don't understand the function of the particle と in the sentence. 
 Can someone elaborate on the use of と in this sentence?

Comment: See the selected answer [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41121). (3rd definition).

Comment: Related or duplicate? : https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23727/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1784/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24463/9831