# Can と indicante the object or the topict too as well as the を and は particles do?

Tags: particle-と, object, topic

I saw sometimes と indicating a topic. Like in the sentence: そんな既視感に戸惑いを感じていると、こちらを見つめる視線に気が付いた ( My attempt of tranlation is "I felt confused by that deja vu feeling by noticing the line of sight looking in this direction"). I think it have the 「そんな既視感に戸惑いを感じている」as the topic of the sentence, and then say that the person had that feeling of deja vu by noticing a line of sight. Is that it or did I got all wrong?

Anothe exemple sentence is: 僕らの存在こんなにも単純だと 笑いに来たんだ (beggining of the opening "UNINSTALL" of the anime ぼくらの).
My teatcher said it means "Came laughing of the fact that our existence is simple this way" (tried to make a more literal translation)

In this last case, it seems that the と have the same role as the particle に, indicanting the element of which someone is laughing.

Comment: As for the lyric line, I'm very sure that it goes 僕らの存在**は**こんなに**も**単純だと.

Comment: I don't know. I got the lyric on Animelon. I don't know if I copied wrong or the site did a wrong transcription. Luckly it does not make much difference on the meaning.

Comment: It semms many sites have wrong transcriptions. I heard the opening again and noticed that there is a も there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, と is not a topic marker. The と in the first sentence just means "when/while ～" or "～ and (then)". (See: [What is the function of と in verb-ていると form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23727/5010)) This 既視感 refers to something mentioned in the previous sentence (because there is そんな), and 視線 refers to a different event that is probably unrelated to the cause of the 既視感.

> I felt confused by that déjà vu feeling, when I (suddenly) noticed someone's eyes staring at me.

---

Your second "sentence" contains a typo, and is actually a **part** of a sentence. The full sentence is:

> 《あの時最高のリアルが向こうから会いに来たの》**は**、「僕らの存在はこんなにも単純だ」と笑いに来たんだ。
> <sub>(punctuation added by me)</sub>

The topic of this sentence is a long nominalized clause (parentheses) and is explicitly marked with the topic marker は (bold). The と after 単純だ is just a quotative-と used with 笑う. The quote is enclosed in the brackets. Xと笑う means "to laugh saying/thinking X".

A very literal translation is:

> As for (the fact) that "the best real" came over to see me at that time, (it) was that he ("the best real") came to laugh at me saying our existence is simple like this.

Taking [the whole context](http://j-lyric.net/artist/a04d013/l00aa41.html) into consideration, this sentence can be interpreted like so:

> I remember the day "the ultimate reality" came over to see me; he came to laugh at me and teach me how trivial our existence is.

<sub>(Note that 最高の is a sarcasm here. Clearly, he does not want to accept the ruthless reality that he is just a piece of dust in this universe.)</sub>

Comment: I got now the meaning of the と of the first sentence. That meaning isn't included on Jisho.org. But i don't understand very well that quotation role of the と particle. I understand that it indicates something that is some kind of target of a verb, but I don't know when it's suitable to use it. I mean, for exemple, every fact expressed with a clause ending with だ, like in the last clause, can be quoted to be a target of any verb?

Comment: I think that first と is just like そして (I coudn't edit the last comment to add this).

Comment: @TitoMorennoPonteseSouza Edited the first paragraph of my answer. Could you check the added link? Although this と is "conditional", it can refer to something that happened by chance while you're doing something.

Comment: @TitoMorennoPonteseSouza the と in the first sentence is the first definition of と on Jisho https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%A8